# Peak Finding Algorithm error: why the peak is surely in the left or the right part of the array?

Tags: c, arrays

For the peak finding problem in one dimensional array why it is coded that if array[mid] is less than a[mid-1] , then surely the left part of the array contains the peak element and if array[mid] is greater than a[mid-1] ,then peak element is in the right part of the array?

Comment: This assumes that there is a single global peak, and the values to the left of the peak are [strictly increasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function#Monotonicity_in_calculus_and_analysis), and the values to the right of the peak are strictly decreasing. A [bell curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) is an example of a function that fits these requirements (if you were to plot the array values versus the array index).

Comment: but then a peak is considered only when both the sides are smaller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First notice that the algorithm finds **a** peak but not necessarily the highest peak.

So draw a graph and imagine it as a picture of mountains. Now if you stand in some point and wants to get to a peak, the algorithm simply says: **Go uphill**

In other words:

If the point to the left is higher than your point, go to the left.

Else if the point to the right is higher than your point, go to the right.

[image]

Comment: Okk so that was the thing.Can you please explain me how the complexity of the code for this is 0(logn)?

Comment: @Kamalpapnai Because in each step you reduce the number of elements to search in to the half. In other words - if you have 1000 elements in one step, there is only 500 in the next and 250 in the next and so on.

Comment: @Kamalpapnai So the worst number of steps will be `m` where `n = 2^m` which gives `m = log(n)/log(2)` so we say that complexity is `log n`